# Reloading lightbox after ajax content loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

There are a couple of similar questions/answers out there, but I haven't been able to apply them.  I'm pretty green.  Any help is appreciated.

I'm working with CubePortfolio - It's a jquery based, filterable project gallery.  Each "project" has the option to either load a more detailed project pop-up page using ajax or to open a lightbox which can then be clicked through to view the cover photos for each project.

Ultimately, I'm trying to add the same lightbox functionality to the ajax loaded pop-up page so the user can then click through the photos specific to that project.

Before requesting the ajax content, that's as simple as adding the .cbp-lightbox class to my  code.  Once the ajax is loaded however, that no longer works.

I'm pretty sure that I understand that I need to re-call (better term?) the JS once the ajax content is loaded, but the lightbox functionality is built in with the rest of the JS code for the filters, responsive grid, etc and uses the delegate (.cpb-lightbox).  I'm lost and hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

The page in question is:
http://www.4sdesignstudio.com/Metalset/projects.html#cbp=../Metalset/cubeportfolio/ajax/lafayette-veterans.html

Working code within my base page (projects.html) - The first  pulls in the ajax loaded pop-up.  The secodn  opens the lightbox.  Both work from the original page but the lightbox won't pull once the ajax is loaded.

```
  <!-- PROJECT 2 - Lafayette Veterans Building -->
                <li class="cbp-item arch">
                    <div class="cbp-caption">
                        <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                            <img src="../Metalset/cubeportfolio/img/lafayette-veterans-cover.jpg" alt="" width="100%"><!-- images pointing towards Metalset folder... will need to updated to local folder once on new server-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                            <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                    <a href="../Metalset/cubeportfolio/ajax/lafayette-veterans.html" class="cbp-singlePage cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft">more info</a>
                                    <a href="../Metalset/cubeportfolio/img/lafayette-veterans-big.jpg" class="cbp-lightbox cbp-l-caption-buttonRight" data-title="Jobsite name and other info">view larger</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">Lafayette Veterans Building</div>
                    <div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-desc">Architectural Metal</div>
                </li>
```

At the bottom of my base page (projects.html)

```
  <!-- load jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../test-platform/cubeportfolio/js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- load cubeportfolio plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../test-platform/cubeportfolio/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js"></script>

    <!-- load main js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../test-platform/cubeportfolio/js/main.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery(document).ready( function() {
             jQuery('#grid-container').cubeportfolio({
                // options
             });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('#grid-container').cubeportfolio({
            /**
             *  This callback function will be trigger after the singlePage popup will be opened. (@param item = the current item clicked)
             */
            singlePageCallback: function (item) {
                // add content to singlePage
                this.updateSinglePage('<div>My content to append to singlePage container</div>');

            }
        });
    </script>
```

Code within my ajax loaded page (lafayette-veterans.html):

```
 <!-- BEGIN MEDIA THUMBNAIL GALLERY --> 
 <div class="cbp-l-project-details">
     <div class="cbp-l-project-details-title"><span>Media Gallery</span></div>

        <a href="../Metalset/cubeportfolio/img/lafayette-veterans-big.jpg" class="cbp-lightbox" data-title="TBD">
            <img src="cubeportfolio/img/lafayette-veterans-big.jpg" style="width:150px; height:auto"></a>
        <a href="../Metalset/cubeportfolio/img/lafayette-veterans-big.jpg" class="cbp-lightbox" data-title="TBD">
            <img src="cubeportfolio/img/lafayette-veterans-big.jpg" style="width:150px; height:auto"></a>
        <a href="../Metalset/cubeportfolio/img/lafayette-veterans-big.jpg" class="cbp-lightbox" data-title="TBD">
            <img src="cubeportfolio/img/lafayette-veterans-big.jpg" style="width:150px; height:auto"></a>
        <a href="../Metalset/cubeportfolio/img/lafayette-veterans-big.jpg" class="cbp-lightbox" data-title="TBD">
            <img src="cubeportfolio/img/lafayette-veterans-big.jpg" style="width:150px; height:auto"></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Lightbox function within the larger JS file:

```
  // LIGHTBOX
        if (t.$obj.find(t.options.lightboxDelegate)) {

            t.lightbox = Object.create(popup);

            t.lightbox.init(t, 'lightbox');

            t.$obj.on('click' + eventNamespace, t.options.lightboxDelegate, function(e) {

                t.lightbox.openLightbox(t.blocksAvailable, this);

                e.preventDefault();

            });

        }
```

Assigned delegate for the lightbox is .cbp-lightbox

Answer (score 1):

Call the lightbox js functions after your ajax.done

https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/js/lightbox.js
Line 10. Name the function and then call it by name?

If u have:

```
var request = $.ajax({ ... });
...
request.done(function(xml) { ... lightboxFunc(); });
```

Comment: Do I call the js function within the ajax html or the original html?  It already gets called within the base page (projects.html).